# Why is this simple AngularJS ng-show is not working to show sublist?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I cannot understand why this AngularJS app not working as intended. "**showPanelSubSystem**" is supposed to show each sublist when its value is true, but it doesnt work.I have to show a Panel list of each Item I get from querystring to my page.So I have a TarrifTopSystemList that comes from Backend hard code.Then I add a ng-repeat in my div tag to show the main list . for showing the div I use **ng-show = "topSystem.showPanel"** . and for showing the subList of TarrifTopSystemList That I mentioned as a SubSystemList I use ng-show = **"ng-show="subSystem.showPanelSubSystem"** .

html :

```html
 <div ng-repeat="topSystem in TarrifTopSystemList" class="padInBox">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                               
                                <div class="panel-heading1">
                                 
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_{{$index}}"
                                           ng-click="showPanelCk(topSystem,$event)"
                                           style="color:#f7fafb !important; text-decoration : none !important"
                                           class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                                            <label> <b>{{topSystem.TopSystemName}}</b></label>
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                              
                                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in"
                                     style="" id="collapse_{{$index}}">
                                   
                                    <div class="panel-body" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #304352, #d7d2cc);"
                                         ng-show="topSystem.showPanel">
                                       
                                        <div class="row ">
                                            <div class="col-md-12  rtlPart">
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="row" style="margin:0;"
                                                         ng-repeat="subSystem in topSystem.SubSystemList">
                                                        <div class="panel-heading1">
                                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}"
                                                                   ng-click="showPanelCk1(subSystem,$event)"
                                                                   style="color:#f7fafb !important; text-decoration : none !important"
                                                                   class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                                                                    <label style="color: white !important;">
                                                                        <b style="color: white !important;">{{subSystem.SubSystemName}}</b>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div ng-show="subSystem.showPanelSubSystem">
                                                            <div class="panel-collapse collapse"
                                                                 ng-class="{'panel-collapse collapse in' : ($index == 0 && $parent.$index == 0)}"
                                                                 id="collapse_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}">
                                                                <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: whitesmoke !important">
                                                                    <div class="row ">
                                                                        <div class="col-md-12  rtlPart">
                                                                            <div>
                                                                                <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
                                                                                    <div class="panel-heading1">
                                                                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                                <td></td>
                                                                                                <td style="width: 50px !important;">Payment Code</td>
                                                                                                <td style="width: 700px !important;">Payment Type</td>
                                                                                                <td style="width: 50px !important;">Amount</td>
                                                                                                <td></td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                                                                            <tr ng-repeat="paymentType in subSystem.PaymentTypeList"
                                                                                                ng-class="{'succeedColor': paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.IsPaid == true &&
                                                                                            ((paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.IsOnline && paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.BankResultCode == 0) ||
                                                                                            ((!paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.IsOnline && paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.BankResultCode == 2))),
                                                                                            'pendingColor': paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.BankResultCode == 1,
                                                                                            'rejectedColor':(paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.BankResultCode == 3 ||
                                                                                            paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.BankResultCode == -1)}">
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="select"
                                                                                                           ng-model="paymentType.IsSelected" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td style="width: 50px !important;">
                                                                                                    <label style="color: white !important;">
                                                                                                        <b style="color: black !important;">{{paymentType.PaymentTypeId}}</b>
                                                                                                    </label>
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td style="width: 700px !important;text-align: right;" dir="auto">
                                                                                                    <label style="color: white !important;">
                                                                                                        <b style="color: black !important;">{{paymentType.PaymentTypeName}}</b>
                                                                                                    </label>
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td style="width: 50px !important;">
                                                                                                    <label style="color: white !important;">
                                                                                                        <b style="color: black !important;">{{paymentType.Amount}}</b>
                                                                                                    </label>
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <button ng-click="showModalPayment($index,$parent.$index,$parent.$parent.$index)"
                                                                                                            class="btn btn-success"
                                                                                                            ng-disabled="!paymentType.IsSelected"
                                                                                                            ng-show="!paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.IsPaid &&
                                                                                                        paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.BankResultCode != 2">
                                                                                                        پرداخت
                                                                                                    </button>
                                                                                                    <!--paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.PaymentId,paymentType.PaymentTypeName-->
                                                                                                    <button ng-click="onShowPayStatus($index,$parent.$index,$parent.$parent.$index)"
                                                                                                            class="btn btn-info"
                                                                                                            ng-show="paymentType.IsSelected &&
                                                                                                        paymentType.PaymentTarrifCodeInfo.PaymentId">
                                                                                                        استعلام پرداخت
                                                                                                    </button>
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                                                                        </table>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                           


                        </div>
```

js :

```js
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.register.controller('TarrifPaymentListController',
        [
            '$scope',
            '$window',
            '$translate',
            'dataService',
            '$routeParams',
            '$rootScope',
            'toaster',
            '$location',
            'modalService',
            '$timeout',
           
            function ($scope, $window, _, dataService, $routeParams, $rootScope,
                toaster, $location, modalService, $timeout) {
                $scope.viewModel = {};
                var requestId = $location.search().id;
                var refCode = $location.search().ReferenceCode;
                var requestPrefix = refCode.split("-")[0];
                var requestType;
                if (requestPrefix == "AMO") {
                    requestType = 1
                }
                else if (requestPrefix == "MF") {
                    requestType = 0
                }
                else if (requestPrefix == "MG") {
                    requestType = 3
                }
                else {
                    requestType = 4
                }
                var getTarrifList = function (requestId, requestType) {

                    var en = {
                        ReuestId: requestId,
                        ReuestType: requestType
                    };
                    dataService.save(en, 'api/RequestPayment/GetTarrifCodeList/')
                        .then(function (data) {
                            if (data.Succeed) {
                                $scope.TarrifTopSystemList = data.TarrifTopSystemList;
                                $scope.TarrifTopSystemList[0].showPanel = true;
                                if (requestType == 1) {
                                    $timeout(function () {
                                        

                                 $scope.TarrifTopSystemList[0].SubSystemList[0].showPanelSubSystem = true;

                                    });
                                }
                                else if (requestType == 0) {
                                    $timeout(function ($scope) {
                                        debugger;
                                        
                                 $scope.TarrifTopSystemList[0].SubSystemList[1].showPanelSubSystem = true;
                                       
                                    },);
                                }

                            } else {

                                toaster.pop('error', _("Dataservice_TTL_Save"), data.Message);
                            }
                        });
                };
```

Comment: Please add a working jsfiddle and hardcode your API data in a service. SO that we can see what your error is. Thanks you can put your above code here https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/ its boilerplate to run angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.TarrifTopSystemList[0].SubSystemList[0].showPanelSubSystem = true`

It seemed that you set only first item whether show or unshow.
If you'd like to set each panel show or unshow in TarrifTopSystemList using ng-repeat,
you should set each TarrifTopSystemList to set.

`$scope.TarrifTopSystemList[0].SubSystemList[0].showPanelSubSystem = true; $scope.TarrifTopSystemList[1].SubSystemList[0].showPanelSubSystem = false;`

If you post your hope layout image and current actual image,
we can make sense easily and response correctly
because your question is about GUI layout.